# How do I chain state updates?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with multiple controls that saves everything to a variable. Each control has an `onChanged` function, which runs a state update with that control's new value:

```
function onChangedValUpdate(newVal){
  let fields = clone(this.state.fields);
  fields[controlId] = newVal;
  this.setState({fields});
}
```

My controls are dynamically created, and when they are, they run `onChangedValUpdate` on their initial value, if one is present. The problem is, sometimes a lot of controls are created at once, and React queues up its `setState`s using the same cloned `fields` object for each update. The object is not updated between `setState`s, presumably for similar reasons to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately) This means that, effectively, all but one control's updates are overwritten.

I tried writing an over-smart routine which used `setState`'s callback to only run it if there isn't one already in progress and remember changes made to the `fields` variable in between `setState`s, but React went and ran all my queued updates simultaneously. Regardless, the routine felt too contrived to be right.

I'm sure this is a trivial and solved problem, but I can't seem to formulate my question in a Googleable way. How do I chain state updates that happen concurrently, and of which there may be any number?

**EDIT** For posterity, my solution, thanks to Yuri:

```
function onChangedValUpdate(newVal){
  this.setState( state => {
    let fields = clone(state.fields);
    fields[controlId] = newVal;
    return {fields};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a mutation function to `setState`. This will prevent overwritting on batched updates because every callback will get the most recent previous state.

```
function onChangedValUpdate(newVal){
  this.setState(function(state){
    const fields = clone(state.fields)

    fields[controlId] = newVal

    return {fields: fields}
  });
}
```

Or using object spread and enhanced object literals.

```
function onChangedValUpdate(newVal){
  this.setState(({fields}) => ({fields: {...fields, [controlId]: newVal}}));
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I didn't know I could do this. I wrapped my function inside `setState` and cloned its passed state object to do mutations on. Now all controls are being written as they should be.